# Don't validate untouched fields in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, validation

I have reactive form and don't want validation to be triggered until user really visits a field.

For example, this is a field:

```
<input type="text" [formControl]="customerNumber">
```

And this is the component:

```
customerNumber: FormControl = new FormControl(
    null, {validators: [Validators.required]
});
```

As you see, its simple. The issue I have is that validation is triggered when the form is displayed and the input field gets `ng-invalid` class, even it is not *touched*.

I need validation to be triggered only after the user touches the field.

Comment: I am aware that in Angular 1.5 whilst validating you could check for `input.$touched` But, I'm not familiar with Angular 2's syntax. It might be worth checking out the NG2 validation docs https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: @FrancisLeigh I can check if the field is touched, but I do not need that. I want validation engine to not validate the field if it is not touched. In other words, I want Angular2 to check that, not me.

Comment: So basically you want the field to be optional until the user touches it. So you should begin by removing Validators.required from the initial configuration. Then you listen to an event that gets triggered when you touch the field, and programmatically set the field to be required. Sounds like it should be possible, but I dont know the available options. You could console log the form to see what methods and events are available to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As somebody mentioned in the comments:

Initial config:

`customerNumber: FormControl = new FormControl(null);`

Subscribe to value changes and set your validator only if a validator is not already set:

```
this.sub = this.form.controls.customerNumber.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
   if (!this.form.controls.customerNumber.validator) {  
       this.form.controls.customerNumber.setValidators(Validators.required);
   }
})
```

If you need to perform validation on the value that triggered validator setup
make sure to call:

```
this.form.controls.customerNumber.updateValueAndValidity();
```

immediately after the setup.

Also, make sure to unsubscribe once you are done with the component:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.usubscribe();
}
```

EDIT

Another option would be to create a custom required validator that validates only if the control is dirty.:

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

function customRequiredValidator(c: FormControl) {
    if(!c.dirty)
    {
      return null;
    }
    ...
}
```

You can then just import it wherever needed and use it in place of the Validators.required.

Comment: And I have to do this for _every_ component I have? :(

Comment: There are other options. You could write your custom required validator that checks for dirty and than reuse that across your app instead of the Validators.required. Or you could simply expand the *ngIf condition in your template so that you do not  show a validation error in case the control is not dirty. Here's a stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uhjydn

Comment: You do not want to have a empty required field having a valid state just because the user didn't touch it.

Comment: could you add the idea about custom Validators in the Answer? For me, that is the way to go. I have a set of custom validators that first check if a value is untouched or if it is `null` - and then validate only if initial value changes, meaning component was touched. This is for me very clean way.

Comment: I 've added it. I am still curios about your use-case. Why would you like to have a empty required field marked as valid? That would mean that the user can proceed and save the form if he does not touch the required field?

Comment: of course we don't allow that - but since on submit we do copy from FormControl to model, it is easier to check if something is missing and disable the submission. And our requirements says that no error should be shown until user enters the field or click on submit.

Comment: for the record, I can't believe this common UX case is not covered by Angular. Sorry for ranting, but I hate hacking frameworks.