# Why does my form validate all default value (untouched field) as soon as the page is loaded?

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, jhipster, angular-reactive-forms

We have an issue about the use of Validators.required or its understanding for our form.

We want an input text to be mandatory (Validators.required). 
Its default value is empty ('').
The user has to put some text in it.

The problem is that the something is playing the Validators.required when we arrive on the page. In other word, the input text is already in red, flagged as invalid as soon as the page is refreshed.

For example, what we are trying to do is here https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/validation, in order to make the field 'First Name *:' invalid, we have to focus the field, type some stuff, erase everything and loose focus.

We use Angular 7 and PrimeNG.
If we copy/past the source code from PrimeNG, we have the same issue.
But if we replace the Validators.required by Validators.pattern('\d{4}') for instance, everything works fine: the user has to put some stuff first in the input and only then, the Validators kicks in.
The form become invalid just after the initialization from this.fb.group(...).

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myform = this.fb.group({
        'minBreak':  new FormControl('', Validators.required) 
    });
}


<div style="display: flex; width: 28em;">
    <span style="margin-right: 1em;">
            Min break
    </span>
    <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="minBreak" />
</div>
```

**The problem**
As soon as 
`this.myform = this.fb.group({
            'minBreak':  new FormControl('', Validators.required) 
        });`
is done, the form go to the status = INVALID.
We would expect it to be VALID.

**The question**
Why our form become invalid after its initialization? Is it normal to run the Validators on default value? If so, why on the example here https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/validation it is not the case?

**Stackblitz**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pnyiy3 in the console, we can see that the form status is INVALID.

Thanks for your help :)

**NB** For those who use JHipster, they put

```
.ng-invalid:not(form) {border-left: 5px solid red;}
```

in the global.scss. Once removed, everything works fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [angular doc](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#required) the validator require a non-empty value.

So even though there is an error you don't have to display it, instead you can wait for the form to be dirty and to have an error to display this error.

You can find a working repro here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a3vjbk

Comment: Thanks for your help :) Yes it does require a non empty field but how do you explain the behaviour observed in here https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/validation all required field are not validated when the page is loaded. We have to put some input in them, erase it, and loose focus in order to make them "invalid".

Comment: Actually, they are invalid and you can see it beceause you can't click on the submit page until you fill all of them. But the page inform the user of the error only if he makes the field dirty and let it invalid as shown in the example

Comment: Oh, I see. You do have a point here. So it is only a matter of CSS. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### You need to check if your form is "dirty" before showing any error or validation message.

In your code sample, you are just rendering the error message on the HTML. You need to check if the field is valid and also if the form is "dirty". You can do that using the [*ngIf directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) and put it into your span tag.

Check in the validationdemo.html file example of the [website](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/validation) you mentioned on your question:

```
 <p-message severity="error" 
            [text]="Error"
    *ngIf="!userform.controls['password'].valid&&userform.controls['password'].dirty">
```

**userform.controls['password'].valid** checks if your field password is valid
**userform.controls['password'].dirty** checks if your field is "dirty". Your field becomes dirty if you clicked, changed the value or pressed any key while focusing the field.

Comment: Thanks for your response and rapidity! But our <span> Min break </span> is not the error message, it is the label of the input text. Actually, we don't want any message to be shown, we only want the input text to be unvalid 'in red'. We thought that Validators.required was enough and Angular to be smart enough to check dirtyness by its own.

Comment: fyi - angular adds a helpful classes like `ng-dirty` `ng-touched` `ng-invalid` `ng-valid` to the element. if all you want is to a red border around them, just use those with CSS rules. no js required.

Comment: ohh, I see now. The border color of the input should be changed automatically. Can you reproduce in a StackBlitz or JsFiddle? Also take a look at @Stavm 's suggestion.

Comment: @LucasNesk here is the stackblitz :) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pnyiy3 do you know why the status is INVALID?

Comment: @Stavm thanks for CSS classes (we might use them later :)) but the problem here is that our form is INVALID as soon as the page is loaded :(. Angular seems to run Validators even for the default value... The form should be INVALID after we put some text in the box/erase it and loose focus. Or maybe we are wrong?

Comment: @Pilpo thanks for the stackblitz! I checked and you are right. The form status is INVALID at the init of the component. I think you should check also "this.myform.dirty" to achieve 100% of the feature you want. I believe the dirty property is used also by the Validators. Please check this Stack: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hasw6r

Comment: @LucasNesk The form is indeed 'not dirty' at the beginning. But I find it very strange we have to "customize" the Validators. I thought Angular would have known that, at first, our input is not dirty. I stumbled across this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708899/dont-validate-untouched-fields-in-angular2 but as I said before, I find it odd we have to do all that :(

Exactly, as you said 'the dirty property is used also by the Validators' I thought the same but our example is the contrary, it doesn't seem to use it, no?

Comment: @LucasNesk as lewisbm suggested, the form is also invalid on the primeng example because we can't submit it. So only css needed for my case :)